# Running sum using the Dynamic Linq library

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

Given the following list:

```
var items = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 5 };
```

I am trying to calculate a total of previous records for any given record using the [Dynamic Linq library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Library/). In standard LINQ (LINQ to Objects), I could do this:

```
var runningTotal = 0;
var qry1 = items.Select(x => {
    var ret = new { x, runningTotal };
    runningTotal += x;
    return ret;
});
```

or this (less efficient, because it's iterating over all the previous items in the list each time. This is obviously not an issue for such a small list, but it will be for larger ones):

```
var qry1 = items.Select((x, idx) => new { 
    x, 
    runningTotal = items.Take(idx).Sum()
});
```

The library doesn't implement `Take` within a string expression, or an overload of `Select` that takes the index of the element. However, the following almost gets there:

```
var qry2 = items.AsQueryable().Select(
    "new(it as x, @0.Where(it < parent).Sum(it) as runningTotal)",
    items
);
```

However, this suffers from a few shortcomings:

- The list must have some order to it, or else the inner `Where` will return arbitrary records
- For the same reason, each item must be unique
- This suffers from the same inefficiency as the second C# example

Is there any way to do this using Dynamic Linq, which doesn't have these problems, and if yes then how?

---

**Update**

I tried writing the following class:

```
[DynamicLinqType]
public class Aggregator<T> {
    private T state;
    private Func<T, T, T> fn;
    public Aggregator(Func<T, T, T> fn) {
        this.fn = fn;
    }
    public T GetState(T value) {
        state = fn(state, value);
        return state;
    }
}
```

and then querying like this:

```
var aggregator = new Aggregator<int>((runningTotal1, x) => runningTotal1 + x);
var qry4 = items.AsQueryable().Select(
    "new(it as x, @0.GetState(it) - it as runningTotal)", 
    aggregator
);
```

but I get a `ParseException: Methods on type 'Aggregator1' are not accessible` even though the `GetState` method is public. This is because the library restricts itself to using only members of certain predefined types, as well as types marked with `DynamicLinqTypeAttribute` (by default). But the marked type `Aggregator<T>` is not the same as the constructed type (`Aggregator<int>`).

---

**Update 2**

I have filed an [issue about running calculations](https://github.com/NArnott/System.Linq.Dynamic/issues/47) and another issue about [generic combinations of recognized types](https://github.com/NArnott/System.Linq.Dynamic/issues/48).

Comment: `var items = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 5 };` how come you can't just do items.Sum()` are you wanting to total up the values to equal `11`

Comment: @MethodMan I want each element of the returned query to be the element of the list, and the sum of all previous elements. The journey matters as much as the destination.

Comment: why does it have to be in linq, why not just a simple loop?

Comment: @AD.Net Because this is part of a reporting system which relies on properties of objects.

Comment: what version DynamicLInq you use?

Comment: missed this link :-)

Comment: damn :-D i missed all in your question :-D missed link, missed last paragraph :-D

Comment: @ZevSpitz, do you apply it only to Objects? or to some sql providers also?

Comment: @Grundy I don't think there is any way to do this using Linq to EF, or Linq to SQL. My experience is with SQL Server providers, and AFAIK there is no built-in mapping from .NET syntax to SQL Server window functions.

Answer (score 3):

I do a bit research and found where is error:

`DynamicLinqType` register type - in your case `Aggregator<T>`

So when you specify `T` to *int* this already another type `Aggregator<int>`, and `DynamicLinq` think that it not predifined type.

So as a solution you can just remove generic part:

```
[DynamicLinqType]
public class Aggregator
{
    private int state;
    private Func<int, int, int> fn;
    public Aggregator(Func<int, int, int> fn)
    {
        this.fn = fn;
    }
    public int GetState(int value)
    {
        state = fn(state, value);
        return state;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
yet another way - fix this in source:

```
static bool IsPredefinedType(Type type)
{
    if (_predefinedTypes.Contains(type)) return true;

    if (GlobalConfig.CustomTypeProvider.GetCustomTypes().Contains(type)) return true;

    // for generic type check GenericTypeDefinition
    if (type.IsGenericType && GlobalConfig.CustomTypeProvider.GetCustomTypes().Contains(type.GetGenericTypeDefinition())) return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I would fix this a little differently: `if (type.IsGenericType && IsPredfinedType(type.GetGenericTypeDefinition()) && type.GenericTypeArguments().All(IsPredefinedType)) return true;`. This is a little more concise, and also checks the type parameters -- `Wrapper<Random>` won't be included. I will post a pull request shortly.

Comment: @ZevSpitz, i think not need check generic parameters, because if they provie on register: first contains get it, if not - apply generic definition